# How can I send an smtplib email to mulitple groups in python?

Tags: python, email, join, smtplib

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

list1=[
    'Person 1 <email1@outlook.com>',
    'Person 2 <email2@gmail.com>'
    ]
    
list2=[
    'Person 3 <email3@yahoo.com>',
    'Person 4 <email4@hotmail.com>'
    ]
    
masterlist = [list1, list2]

for x in masterlist:
    receivers = ", ".join(x)

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'This is a Test Email'
msg['From'] = 'Person 5 <email5@outlook.com>'
msg['To'] = receivers
msg.set_content('Ignore this message')

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

This is the code that I have used.I would like to send this email out to certain groups, but *not* join all emails into one email. The way I have it now, only ends up sending the email out to the last list of emails. How should I modify this to be able to send it to multiple lists of emails?

Comment: `receivers = list1 + list2`

Comment: I had a typo in my post. I was trying to send an email to each list separately. I believe by making `receivers = list1 + list2` I end up sending the email to all people in one email.

Answer (score 0):

You're only passing the last list of emails to `msg['To']` because the program overwrites the previous lst assignments with last item in lst. So why want you just concatenate the two lists to send the email to everyone?

```
#masterlist = [list1, list2]

#for x in masterlist:
   #receivers = ", ".join(x)
# The .join() function doesn't do much in this situation because your lists are already separated by commas.

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'This is a Test Email'
msg['From'] = 'Person 5 <email5@outlook.com>'
msg['To'] = list1 + list2 # or use .extend() function the same is accomplished
msg.set_content('Ignore this message')
```

So just get rid of the `masterlist` variable and the `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my original post. I want this to send out two separate emails one for each list of emails.`list1 + list2` sends the email out to all parties.

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

list1=[
    'Person 1 <email1@outlook.com>',
    'Person 2 <email2@gmail.com>'
    ]
    
list2=[
    'Person 3 <email3@yahoo.com>',
    'Person 4 <email4@hotmail.com>'
    ]
    
masterlist = [list1, list2]

for x in masterlist:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'This is a Test Email'
    msg['From'] = 'Person 5 <email5@outlook.com>'
    msg['To'] = x
    msg.set_content('Ignore this message')

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

I was able to correct this by making the email section in to a for loop based on the list of emails.